# Silverstripe - get parent page fields from blog Widget

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have a custom widget in the sidebar of BlogPosts which I want to display other BlogPosts for the current BlogPost author...to do this the widget needs to know about the page it is on and retrieve (ie) the AuthorName and other details from the BlogPost page...but I'm at a loss how to navigate up from the Widget to the BlogPost...

```
|  Blog post by Jim 1    |                     |
|                        |More posts by {Jim}  |
|                        |----------           |
|                        |Jims post 2          |
|                        |Jims post 3          |
|                        |Jims post 4          |
|                        |                     |
```

ok, you get what I mean:) . Any ideas appreciated....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so figured it out - you can use something like this in the widget:

```
public function AuthorName()
{
    $page = Director::get_current_page();
    if ($page && ($page instanceof BlogPost)) {
        //return $page->Title;
        if($author = $page->Authors()){
            return $author->first()->getName();
        }

    }
}
```